# How to query 100 first items ordered by sort key of a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a simple DynamoDB table called `Scores` with 3 attributes:

```markdown
| id                                   | score | username |
|--------------------------------------|-------|----------|
| ed6dbe2f-ffb3-44f3-a5f1-bb84502e5400 | 300   | bob      |
| b8f91dd9-09e6-466b-88f3-9e7b95dc9a3a | 100   | peter    |
| 55dd0bd1-2bc7-4bb7-a988-20e506c2c35c | 500   | bob      |
```

my key attributes are `hash key = id` and `sort key = score`

I want to query the first 100 smallest scores, with the username of the player who scored it, ordered asc.

in SQL, in would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Scores ORDER BY score LIMIT 100;
```

I tried and failed with these tactics:

- use a scan => it returns the items unordered.
- use a query => I don't want to target a specific primary key value
- use a global secondary index with `hash key = username` and `sort key = score` => I can't query only with the sort key, I have to specify the hash key as well

so my poor solution was to perform a scan, then sort and slice in memory... sigh

I'm convinced that a similar problem has already been discussed and solved somewhere, but I already read a lot and I can't find anything.
Can you give me a hint please ?

Comment: Sidenote: I'll bite the bullet and say, if you're trying to retrieve all the data in a DynamoDB table (other than doing an export) - whether there is a sort key or not - there's normally a larger architectural issue.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary well I specified "the first 100 items" so it's not exactly all the data. But I get your point ;)

Comment: Ah title said all rows - sorry

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary you're right it's misleading, I edited the title

Comment: Maybe: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html

Comment: Interesting @ErmiyaEskandary ! I tried, but:
1. to use ORDER BY, you have to also use a WHERE clause
2. the WHERE clause must specify a partition key
so i run in the same problem that above

Comment: Related: [Amazon DynamoDB: Gaming use cases and design patterns](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-gaming-use-cases-and-design-patterns/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a GSI with a singular PK value and the timestamp as the SK. Then you can do a `Query` for the first 1,000 passing a `limit` of 100.

This works, but only up to 1,000 write units, because that singular PK value gets hot. The solution there is to shard. Decide how many write units you need. 10,000? OK so instead of one PK value, use 10. Each item gets randomly assigned a shard number as its GSI PK attribute.

Your query call will have to run 10 queries (client can do in parallel) and coalesce the results client side. Works for any scale of write traffic.

It’s a technique discussed in https://youtu.be/0iGR8GnIItQ (at 33:44).

Comment: Thanks @hunterhacker for your great and detailed answer ! I will definitely use that technique. About the sharding, I don't know how it works in DynamoDB so I'll have to read the documentation first to understand it properly. Your explanation already enlightens a lot of concept about it, thank you for that !