# How to order the result inside the scan operation dynamodb based on an attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

**How to order the result inside the scan operation dynamodb based on an attribute**

need to arrange the scan operation using a attribute in the entity. The attribute value is a timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot choose the order of items during a Scan.

If you want items ordered by timestamp across the table, you can see my previous answer to that question at [How to query 100 first items ordered by sort key of a DynamoDB table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510356/how-to-query-100-first-items-ordered-by-sort-key-of-a-dynamodb-table)